# Subalgebras of $II_{1}$ factor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a type $II_{1}$ factor, Let $B$ is an infinite dimensional nonabelian subalgebra. Is it true that $B$ always type $II_{1}$ ?

Comment: I guess you mean von Neumann subalgebra. What if it's not a factor? If a group VN algebra take the subalgebra generated by a "small" nonabelian subgroup.

Comment: yes vN subalgebra

Comment: What do you mean by small group?

Comment: Nothing precise, whence the quotation marks. What do you think with a nonabelian finite subgroup?

Comment: Oops missed "infinite-dimensional"; but say, with a virtually abelian subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is type $II_1$ then it has a tracial state, and hence so does $B$ by restriction. So if $B$ is an infinite dimensional subfactor it must be type $II_1$, by inspection of factor types. If $B$ is merely a subalgebra then it could have a type $I$ part, e.g. $\mathbb{C}p + qMq$ where $p$ and $q$ are nonzero projections with $p+q=1$.